# Calculating vertical height of a SVG text

Tags: javascript, text, svg, tspan

I have an array of strings. Say,

```
['Jan 11','Feb 11']
```

And i am creating a vertical text with these string like so

```
<text x="60" y="154" text-anchor="middle" style="text-anchor: middle; font: normal normal normal 12px/normal Helvetica, Arial; " font="12px Helvetica, Arial" stroke="none" fill="#ffffff" transform="rotate(90 59.75 150)">
<tspan>Jan 11</tspan>
</text>
```

After the svg has been rendered i find that the height of the text is 36px. Now is there a way to calculate the height of a text that will be rendered beforehand given the font-size?

Answer (score 17):

You can use `getBBox` method to calculate dimensions of the SVG nodes.

```
var textNode = document.getElementsByTagName('text'),
    bbox = textNode.getBBox();

//bbox now have x, y, width and height properties
```

Comment: Yeah. But that is after the node has been rendered. I was looking for a way to calculate height before render using only the array string.

Comment: You can append the node with `visibility="hidden"` specified, then call getBBox, and then unhide it when you've made whatever tweaks you needed. Since svg doesn't use the CSS box model it doesn't affect the layout of other svg elements. It's good to do it like that because some properties on the text element may depend on the context (parent elements, cascaded styles etc).

Comment: Calling getBBox() on hidden nodes with throw an exception in Firefox

Comment: I noticed that they set the "opacity" to 0 in [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/pTVgFuEgCfY) example rather than using visibility. Perhaps to work around problems with Firefox?

Comment: Worth noting calling `getBBox` on text nodes returns inaccurate measurements in IE10 and IE11 https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/791152/svg-getbbox-return-incorrect-value-for-text-elements-in-ie10-serious-bug

Comment: These dimensions and position are relative to the page, not the SVG space. I'm baffled by presence of .getTextLength() but no .getTextHeight() or similar.